# sbt 0.13 task macro equivalent of flatMap

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm upgrading my build to use the new macro syntax as much as I can, and I encountered a `flatMap` that I don't know how to deal with.

Let's say I used to have a task of the following form

```
myTask <<= (foo, bar) flatMap { (x, y) => someFunctionProducingATask(x, y, 5) }
```

Now, `Def.taskDyn` looks vaguely promising, but doesn't quite fit. Translating it to the naive thing doesn't work:

```
myTask <<= Def.taskDyn {
  val x = foo.value
  val y = bar.value
  someFunctionProducingATask(x, y, 5) // ERROR: we need an Initialize[Task[...]], but have a Task[...]
}
```

`Initialize` feels monadic but I can't find a `pure` for it, so I don't know how to put my task into it, or if that's even desirable. The docs don't seem to say anything beyond suggesting I use `taskDyn`. Anyone have any ideas here?

Answer (score 4):

In most user-facing documentation, `"task"` means `Initialize[Task[T]]`.  A `"task"` as builds and plugins usually use them is really a setting whose value is a task.

The `someFunctionProducatATask` should probably return `Initialize[Task[T]]`.

`pure` for `Initialize` is `Def.value` (accepts `=> T`) or `Def.pure` (accepts `() => T`).

However, normally just use `Def.task` (for `Initialize[Task[T]]`) and `Def.setting` (for `Initialize[T]`.  These allow the same syntax as the argument to `:=`, `+=`, and `++=`.

Comment: Oh, in my case `someFunctionProducingATask` is actually `Classpaths.interDependencies` in sbt. Perhaps I should try to rework the code to avoid using that in the first place.

Comment: If you actually need that method, I'm not sure there is an alternative. What are you using it for?

Comment: I wonder if it'd pay to have a type synonym for `X => Initialize[Task[X]]` if it's so common. I'm trying to figure out a succinct way to describe what we're using it for, but it mostly boils down to wanting to call `interDependencies` on a different "task function" for the last argument. I'm still trying to figure out how it works to give better detail.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean for the type synonym to do or what it is that is common.

Comment: I just mean `type Task[A] = Initialize[InternalTask[A]]` where `InternalTask` is the current `Task`. I was responding to your first sentence.

Comment: Oh!  I thought you meant an alias for the value level function.  A type level function makes more sense.  I agree.  I'm not sure the best way to get there in terms of source compatibility, but if you figure it out a pull request is more than welcome.